# Is there any operation on real numbers, defined using only the basic arithmetic operations, which is diassociative, but not associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

By operation I mean binary function from pairs of reals to reals. By diassociative I mean that the subset generated by any two numbers is associative - or, any string composed only of two types of values (like abaab) is unambiguous and needs no parentheses (but with three or more types of values, parentheses may be needed).

I determined yesterday that there is no such operation defined solely as a * b = xa + yb + zab, but I don't know about other more complex definitions.

Update: With some horribly laborious calculations, I found that the set of all commutative and diassociative operations on reals defined x * y = a(x² + y²) + bxy + c(x + y) + d is equivalent to that prior class, due to requiring a to equal 0, and thus they are all associative, so even expanding to that larger set of operations, there are none which are diassociative without being associative.

I feel like there's probably some way, somewhere, to prove that no operation on the reals is diassociative without also being associative - but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I am slightly confused; for example, the addition $a \ast b := a+b$ is associative and from how your question is phrased, I would assume that it would therefore be diassociative as well. I am sure I am misunderstanding something, could you clarify more what "diassociative" means?

Comment: Diassociative means that any string using only two values, like abaab, or whatever, has an unambiguous meaning and doesn't need any parentheses. But with three or more values, parentheses are necessary. Alternative is another term like this but I am not certain they are equivalent. All associative operations are diassociative, but NOT vice versa. I want an operation on reals which is diassociative, but not associative.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the explanation!